# OpenSearch: how to define parent/child relationship between documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, aws-elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

Due to `AWS` migration I have to migrate from `ElasticSearch` to `OpenSearch`. The OpenSearch will be provisioned by [AWS OpenSearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/index.html).

The existing documents in ES index has `parent/child` relationship created using [join field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/parent-join.html). I don't see such mapping type in the [OpenSearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/parent-join.html).

**Question:** How can I define `parent/child` relationship in OpenSearch?

**UPDATED:**
The currently used ES version is `6.8`. As for migration, the preference is to use the latest OpenSearch version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in the documentation, but there's code related to `join field type`, e.g. [ParentJoinFieldMapperTests.java](https://github.com/opensearch-project/OpenSearch/blob/main/modules/parent-join/src/test/java/org/opensearch/join/mapper/ParentJoinFieldMapperTests.java), so I think it's there for you to try.

Comment: Indeed, I started doing a quick POC and was able to create an index with a field of  `join type`